# Windows 10 IoT Core: What is not supported for Discrete TPM (dTPM)

Tags: iot, windows-10-iot-core, tpm

From the link below:

http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SetupTPM.htm#dTPM

There is stated "note that some of the functionality may not be supported by the dTPM, so a few error codes are expected".

May I know what is not supported by the dTPM?

Comment: You should check your *device's* documentation for this. The phrase means "We can give you the API but the device may not support everything"

Answer (score 1):

It is up to the TPM manufacturer which of the optional TPM 2.0 library commands and algorithms beyond mandatory ones are implemented on the discrete or firmware TPMs. Please refer to the [PC Client Platform TPM Profile (PTP) Specification](http://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/files/static_page_files/28CBF489-1A4B-B294-D038AC358AD39A6A/PC%20Client%20Specific%20Platform%20TPM%20Profile%20for%20TPM%202%200%20v43%20150126.pdf) at the TCG and the device datasheet from the TPM manufacturer for details.

Windows does not restrict TPM functionality and makes all TPM provided functionality available through the TPM Based Services (TBS) and supports selected functionality with the CNG Platform Crypto Provider and features like BitLocker and Windows Entropy Seeding.

Have a nice day
S.